# Cannot get client to pass DNS queries through openVPN tunnel

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

I cannot get my openVPN client machine (Windows 10) to pass DNS queries through the VPN tunnel.

I am pushing `10.0.0.1` as a DNS server and the VPN connection shows that it is the DNS server for that connection.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Apple Mobile Device Ethernet
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.2(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 03 September 2015 09:55:59
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 04 September 2015 12:05:04
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.4(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 03 September 2015 11:25:47
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 02 September 2016 12:19:32
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.254
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

The connection creates this route table

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.20.10.1      172.20.10.2     20
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.4     31
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.4     31
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.4    286
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    286
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    286
   **.***.***.***  255.255.255.255      172.20.10.1      172.20.10.2     21  <-- Public VPN Address
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.4     31
      172.20.10.0  255.255.255.240         On-link       172.20.10.2    276
      172.20.10.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.20.10.2    276
     172.20.10.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.20.10.2    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.4    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.20.10.2    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.20.10.2    276
===========================================================================
```

server.conf

```
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
tls-server
tls-auth ta.key 0
dev tun
local 10.0.0.250
port 1194
proto udp
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
status openvpn-status.log
log openvpn.log
verb 6
```

nslookup results in the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup alpha.intranet.app
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.20.10.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    alpha.intranet.app
Address:  127.0.53.53
```

However, forcing nslookup to use the desired DNS server results in:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup alpha.intranet.app 10.0.0.1
Server:  lan.router
Address:  10.0.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    alpha.intranet.app
Address:  10.0.0.251
```

If I manually change the DNS server for `Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3` to `10.0.0.1` nslookup works without forcing a DNS server and my intranet pages load fine.

Any ideas as to why the DNS server for the physical connection is being preferred over the VPN and how can this be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a set of scripts at dnsleaktest.com which removes any existing links to DNS resolvers before the tunnel is created and adds those of the VPN connection. It also reverses this once the connection is closed.

Comment: Can you share these scripts somewhere? Like a gist?

Comment: Hi. This post is a bit out of date. I don't have the scripts any more. As of OpenVPN 2.3.9 adding `block-outside-dns` in the server config file should achieve the same thing. Easier than setting up the scripts on all clients. The scripts are still available from dnsleaktest.com.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
block-outside-dns
```

To your configuration file (of your choice), which is found here:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config
```

on Windows

or in the System tray:

[image: System Tray]

Click edit config, and then add    `block-outside-dns`